# How to link to an anchor inside a closed tab with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion, bootstrap-tabs

I am trying to link to a specific accordion drawer within a specific closed tab, in Bootstrap 4 (which is using `.collapse()`, not jQueryUI's `.accordion()` or `.tabs()` as found in other solutions here). I am almost there, see [this preview](https://preview.algosphere.org/positions/).

But
1) I cannot manage to make the link to an anchor open its corresponding closed tab and jumping to the anchor ;
2) When I refresh the page when the specific tab is opened, it breaks the anchoring of accordions.
3) When I click to a link in the page after clicking an accordion and go back with the browser back button, the url in the address bar is not correctly upduated.

May I have some help please?
Here is [the HTML](https://github.com/algosphere/algo-website/blob/develop/layouts/positions/list.html#L10-L57).
Here is [the JS](https://github.com/algosphere/algo-website/blob/develop/assets/scripts/misc.js#L43-L59).

Especially the following part doesn't seem to work:

```
var activeAccordionTab = $('#' + url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1)).closest('.tab-pane');
    activeAccordionTab.tab('show');
```

Comment: Can you please explain _what exactly_ you want to link to in the given example page?

Comment: I want for example "/positions/#another-perspective-on-fish" to open the "specific" tab and the "another-perspective-on-fish" accordion

Comment: `$('#another-perspective-on-fish').closest('.tab-pane').tab('show')` “works” if the `Specific` tab was already open, but it throws errors if that was not the case (“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined”). Interestingly enough, just `$('#another-perspective-on-fish').closest('.tab-pane')` seems to find the correct element in any case … so it looks like this has something to do with the `tabs` functionality rather …?

Comment: I switched to using full dedicated link/pages for the accordions content, so I do not need an answer any more — but I may leave the question here in case someone has a solution that could benefit others (the links in the question are not relevant any more then).